# Conditionally control the visibility of a background image in a .NET report (rdlc)

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Quick Summary: How can I conditionally control (at run-time) the visibility of a background image in a report using the built in .rdlc report capabilities in .NET (I am using VB).

The Story:
I have a system that creates "certificates". The certificates are created based on a report definition (.rdlc) and displayed as PDF's to the user, they never see the report viewer control. This system has a public test site as well as the live production site. We want to place a water mark image on any of the certificates that are created by the test system. Basically because we don't want someone creating a test certificate and passing it off as a real one. There is a system level flag that is true when the site runs in test mode, I would like to trigger the visibility of the background image that is a watermark ONLY when that variable is TRUE. At this time I am able to pass a report parameter with this test mode variable, but can't find a way to trigger the visibility of the background image.

Please let me know if any more information is need or further clarification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I figured it out quicker than I expected. The trick in this case was to use an Expression for the BackgroundImage property's value (the source is set to Embedded). In my case it looked something like this:

```
=iif(Parameters!ShowTestWaterMark.Value, "WatermarkVoid1", nothing)
```

Where `Parameters!ShowTestWaterMark.Value` is the parameter of True or False, and the `"WatermarkVoid1"` was the name of the embedded image.

While this doesn't directly toggle the visibility of the image, it does meet my requirements to only have the image shown in a specific case.

Comment: Is there a way to specify to have the background image only for the first page? Using Globals!PageNumber doesn't work :(

Comment: @Sen I want to show image conditionally......IIF(First(Fields!AgentId.Value)>0,"REport1","Reprt2").......but this is not working giving me following error....The value of the BackgroundImageValue property for the report section ‘ReportSection0’ is “IIF(First(Fields!AgentId.Value)>0,"REport1","REprot2")”, which is not a valid BackgroundImageValue...any idea plz

Comment: @Ε Г И І И О six years later, you can add a sub report and set the background image. This is the only work around i found.